# disaligned checkbox in CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm using laravel form my project with dompdf module for create pdf reports. I have a problem to show in the same line the checkbox and label.

i'm trying with this:

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br>
```

and this is the result:
[image]

Comment: Please create a [mcve] demonstrating your problem - we cannot help you with the information you have supplied

Answer (score -1):

[check in Bootstrap website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/forms/#default-stacked)

```
<div class="form-check">
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
<label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
Default checkbox
</label>
</div>
```

OR try to use tables

Answer (score -1):

There's some other CSS affecting the alignments. The checkbox and the label are in the same line by default.

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br>
```